# Boto3: Configuration file location

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto, boto3

Is there any way to have Boto seek for the configuration files other than the default location, which is `~/.aws`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not clear from the question whether you are talking about boto or boto3.  Both allow you to use environment variables to tell it where to look for credentials and configuration files but the environment variables are different.

In boto3 you can use the environment variable `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` to tell boto3 where your credentials file is (by default, it is in `~/.aws/credentials`.  You can use `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` to tell it where your config file is (by default, it is in `~/.aws/config`.

In boto, you can use `BOTO_CONFIG` to tell boto where to find its config file (by default it is in `/etc/boto.cfg` or `~/.boto`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install the configuration file (for site-wide settings that all users on this machine will use) in:

```
nano /etc/boto.cfg
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = your_key
aws_secret_access_key = your_password
```

Other possible locations could be:

- (if profile is given) `~/.aws/credentials` for credentials shared between SDKs
- (if profile is given) `~/.boto` for user-specific settings
- `~/.aws/credentials` for credentials shared between SDKs
- `~/.boto` for user-specific settings

Comment: so this means that you can NOT place the configure file wherever you like, but only specific locations as you described above?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can:**

from [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#configuring-credentials)

- Passing credentials as parameters in the boto.client() method
- Passing credentials as parameters when creating a Session object
- Environment variables
- Shared credential file (~/.aws/credentials)
- AWS config file (~/.aws/config)
- Assume Role provider
- Boto2 config file (/etc/boto.cfg and ~/.boto)
- Instance metadata service on an Amazon EC2 instance that has an IAM role configured.

Please check the link for more information.